# How can I convert audio files like WAV or MP3 to video files that I can upload to YouTube?

Tags: windows-7, audio, video, youtube

I have about 15 WAV files that I want to upload to my YouTube channel, but YouTube only accepts video files.  I know that I can open each file up in Movie Maker or some other video editing software and save it as a video like that, but that's too time consuming.

I've tried a few programs that claim to be able to do this in batch format, but I have had no luck as YouTube fails to process my files.  I am at work and don't remember the names of the programs I used, but I figure you all can recommend programs that you know work for a fact.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, I actually recommend using [Windows Movie Maker](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=34). Just drag the song onto the timeline, then export it as any format. It probably won't be any larger than a few megabytes.

You could also attempt using [Lightworks](http://www.lightworksbeta.com/) on Windows, or [VLMC](http://trac.videolan.org/vlmc/). Windows Movie Maker should NOT be time consuming, as it works very quickly on my 800mhz processor.

For Mac, [iMovie](http://www.apple.com/ilife/imovie/) will accomplish the same task in the exact same way.

For Linux, you could use [Cinelerra](http://cinelerra.org/), as it has a graphical interface to work with.

Comment: I specifically mentioned in my question that I know I can use Movie Maker, but that it's too time consuming for the 15 or so files I need to do this for.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I have added more windows options.

Comment: I am using Movie Maker for Windows Live Essentials.  It sucks.  You can't just drop a WAV file into an empty project.  You first have to bring in an image.  Only then will it allow you to drop in a WAV, but even then you have to play around with the time scale to get it to fit the length of the song.  I couldn't imaging doing this for 15 individual songs.  I need a batch processor.  I think the other guy's suggesting to use ffmpeg will be the best bet as soon as I can find a download link.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin the link i included for movie maker is version 2.6. Its the old one included on XP. You will find it very easy to use i think http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=34

Comment: I gave it a try, but, apparently, you can't manually adjust the video/audio bitrates separately.  I want the lowest possible video bitrate, but maintain a 192kb/sec audio bitrate.  To get a high audio bitrate, I have to go with a high video bitrate which yields a huge file size.  If I use a low video bitrate, the audio bitrate is too low and sounds like crap.  I give up.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube won't allow you to upload audio without a video stream, or vice-versa. With a recent version of ffmpeg, the following will attach a black video for the duration of the audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -filter_complex 'color[v1]' -map [v1] -map 0:a \
-c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

`-c:a copy` will not re-encode the audio stream (since youtube will do that itself), but if you want to you can use `libmp3lame` to [encode MP3 audio](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Encoding%20VBR%20(Variable%20Bit%20Rate)%20mp3%20audio), or `libfdk_aac` (or a number of other options depending on your version, see the link) to [encode AAC audio](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide).

If you want to use an image instead of blackness (say, an album cover), you can do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -loop 1 -i image.png -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest output.mp4
```

See [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for information about libx264.